# Value of unused variable changing after subroutine call - Assembly

Tags: gcc, assembly, nasm

I am pretty new to assembly that I'm learning from the last 7 hours (It's an early peek into the courses I had in the next semester starting next month). I read some online tutorials, and the nasm manual and started to port a C program to nasm, just for learning.

```c
int fact(int n)
{
    return (n < 0) ? 1 : n * fact(n - 1);
}
```

I then started to port it to assembly, and had this as my solution:

```asm
fact:
    ; int fact(int n)
    cmp dword ebx, 0    ; n == 0
    je .yes
.no:
    push ebx            ; save ebx in stack
    sub  ebx, dword 1   ; sub 1 from ebx. (n - 1)
    call fact           ; call fact recursively
    pop  ebx            ; get back the ebx from stack
    imul eax, ebx       ; eax *= ebx; eax == fact(n - 1)
    ret
.yes:
    mov eax, dword 1    ; store 1 in eax to return it
    ret
```

I take in a DWORD (int I suppose) in the `ebx` register and return the value in the `eax` register. As you can see I am not at all using the variable `i` that I have declared in the `.bss` section. My variables are like this:

```asm
section .bss
    ; int i, f
    i resb 2
    f resb 2
```

It's 2 bytes for an int right? Okay then I'm prompting the user in the `_main`, getting the input with `_scanf` and then calling the function. Other than this and calling the function, I have no other code that changes the value of `i` variable.

```asm
    mov ebx, dword [i]  ; check for validity of the factorial value
    cmp dword ebx, 0
    jnl .no
.yes:
    push em             ; print error message and exit
    call _printf
    add esp, 4
    ret
.no:
    push dword  0       ; print the result and exit
    push dword [i]
    push rm
    call _printf
    add esp, 12

    call fact           ; call the fact function
    mov dword [f], eax

    push dword [f]      ; print the result and exit
    push dword [i]
    push rm
    call _printf
    add esp, 12
    ret
```

I don't see where I'm modifying the value of `i` variable, on first print before the call to `fact` it is indeed the same value entered by the user, but after calling the function, in the later print, it is printing some garbage value, as the following output:

```
E:\ASM> factorial
Enter a number: 5
The factorial of 5 is 0The factorial of 7864325 is 120
E:\ASM>
```

Any clues? My complete source code is in this gist: https://gist.github.com/sriharshachilakapati/70049a778e12d8edd9c7acf6c2d44c33

Comment: a `dword` is 4 bytes.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelBurr That did the trick. Could you please add that as an answer so I could accept it?

Comment: To confirm Michael's theory: 7864325 is 0x780005 in hex and 0x78 is 120 in decimal. So this has 120 in the high word and 5 in the low word.